# Does anyone know why this Razor code is not compiling?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Could someone help me get this razor syntax snippet to compile?

```
@var count = 0;
@foreach (var column in Enumerable.Range(0, 20).Select(i => "Title " + i) {
    if(count % 5 == 0) { 
        <tr>
    }
    <td>@column</td>
    @if(count % 5 == 4) {
        </tr>
    }
    count++;
}
```

Comment: The two . just before Select don't look right to me

Comment: Sorry, the select .. typo.  Not the crux of my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need the `count` variable. I've made an alternative solution to Darin´s answer:

```
@foreach (var pair in Enumerable.Range(0, 20).Select(i => new { Title = "Title " + i, Index = i }))
{
    if(pair.Index % 5 == 0) { 
        @:<tr>
    }
    <td>@pair.Title</td>
    if(pair.Index % 5 == 4) {
        @:</tr>
    }
}
```

As you can see in Darin´s answer and this answer, you don't need `@` when you are inside a block. Furthermore, your `<tr>` and `</tr>` look "uneven" to the compiler, so we have to force these with `@:<tr>`. And last, `@var count = 0` will have to be in a block like `@{var count = 0}`.

**Update:** If you actually need an index (if you're not using `Range()`) then you can do as follows (using the overload of `Select` which generates an index for each item):

```
@foreach (var pair in yourSource.Select((data, i) => new { Title = "Title " + data, Index = i }))
```

Comment: I actually need the counter because the data isn't really an Enumerable.  Could you modify it to include the counter?

Comment: @Jake Pearson There go you :)

Comment: Thanks for the select(data, i) idea.  I didn't know you could do that.

Comment: @Jake You're welcome :) It´s often useful so an extension-method could be used: http://seesharp.dk/index-number-when-using-linq

Answer (score 2):

```
@{
    var count = 0;
}
@foreach (var column in Enumerable.Range(0, 20).Select(i => "Title " + i)) 
{
    if(count % 5 == 0) 
    { 
        @:<tr>
    }
    <td>@column</td>
    if(count % 5 == 4) 
    {
        @:</tr>
    }
    count++;
}
```

Comment: How do I get this code to be legal? `@{count++;}`  I need `count++` to be outside of the if.

Comment: @Jake Pearson, this code is valid. It just depends on the context where you are using it. Because you are already inside a `@{ ... }` you shouldn't repeat it once again.